# How do you get past the Windows Script Host error when trying to call `nvm use 16.19.0`

Tags: node.js, windows, nvm

I need to set the node version to an older version for a new project I am working on. I am on Windows 11 Pro. This is a new computer that I setup yesterday and is pretty clean from a node perspective.

I have just removed nodejs and installed nvm (v 1.1.10).

After calling `nvm install 16.19.0`, I tried to call `nvm use 16.19.0` and recieved the following error popup:

[image]

Here is the CLI history:

[image]

I was expecting this to set my current node version to 16.19.0.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to do this while running git-bash from Visual Studio Code so when I loaded up git-bash as Administrator I was able to get the `nvm use` call to work correctly.

Sorry for the stupid question, but I didn't see it answered on here anywhere else, so hopefully it will be useful to someone else.